# Residual standard error for multiple imputed regression

Tags: r, regression, standard-error, multiple-imputation, pooling

How to calculate the standard deviation of the residuals for a pooled regression? (The idea, formula and/or R code are all welcomed)

As far as I understand it is the standard deviation of the estimated and actual values.
From [Statology](https://www.statology.org/how-to-interpret-residual-standard-error/)
[image: Residual standard error]

How to calculate this for a regression with multiple imputation? That is, to pool the residual standard error and get the equivalent for `summary(linear_model)$sigma` for regression analysis for multiple imputed data?

Below is my attempt at it. It would be tempting to just take the mean of the values (v1) but I assume that will have to use something more sophisticated, like [rubin's rule](https://bookdown.org/mwheymans/bookmi/rubins-rules.html) *( see v2, which is heavily borrowed from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/327237/138594), I believe that the problem is in the `betweenVar`-variable as I do not know what the coefficients would be in this case. If the coefficient was 0, then the v1 (mean) would suffice. This would make sense as the residuals should be normally distributed around zero. In that case, the between variance would also be zero and could be dropped from the formula. Or what am I missing here ? )*

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(mice)
library(miceadds)
library(reprex) # does not work with this
library(styler)
set.seed(42)
options(warn=-1)
options(knitr.duplicate.label = "allow")

#---------------------------------------#
# Data preparations

# loading an editing data
d <- mtcars
d <- d %>% mutate_at(c('cyl'),factor)

# create missing data and impute it
mi_d <- d
nr_of_NAs <- 30
for (i in 1:nr_of_NAs) {
  mi_d[sample(nrow(mi_d),1),sample(ncol(mi_d),1)] <- NA
}

#multiple imputation
mi_d <- mice(mi_d, m=2, maxit=2)
#---------------------------------------#
# regressions

#not imputed
lm_d <- lm(qsec ~ cyl, data=d) 

#imputed dataset
lm_mi <- with(mi_d,lm(qsec ~cyl))
lm_mi_pool <- pool(lm_mi)


# residual standard error
#not imputed:
summary(lm_d)$sigma #1.489994

#-------------------------------------------------
# residual standard error
# imputed 
# v1 (probably too simple)

summaries <- lapply(lm_mi$analyses,summary)
residual_standard_errors <- sapply(summaries,"[[","sigma")
pooled_residual_standard_error <- mean(residual_standard_errors) # ????????
pooled_residual_standard_error # 1.490252



#-------------------------------------------------
# residual standard error
# imputed
# v2 rubin's rule
# Source: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/327237/138594

pooled_rse.F <- function(MI_REG_OBJECT) {
  summaries  <- lapply(lm_mi$analyses,summary)
  rse_vector  <- sapply(summaries,"[[","sigma")
  m          <-  length(rse_vector)
  
  betweenVar <- sd(rse_vector) # variance of variances. I believe that the problem lies (at least) in this variable
  withinVar  <- mean(rse_vector^2) # mean of variances
  totVar    <-  withinVar + betweenVar+ betweenVar/m
  (pooled_rse <- sqrt(totVar)) # standard error
}

pooled_rse <- pooled_rse.F(lm_mi)
pooled_rse


# 1.490436

#------------------------------------------------

# imputed
# v3 rubin's rule
# https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/327237/138594

pooled_rse.F <- function(MI_REG_OBJECT) {
  summaries  <- lapply(lm_mi$analyses,summary)
  rse_vector  <- sapply(summaries,"[[","sigma")
  m          <-  length(rse_vector)
  beta_hat    <- mean(apply(sapply(summaries,"[[","residuals"),2,mean))
  
  betweenVar <- sqrt(sum((rse_vector-beta_hat)^2)/(m-1)) #variance of estimates
  withinVar  <- mean(rse_vector^2) # mean of variances
  totVar    <-  withinVar + betweenVar+ betweenVar/m
  (pooled_rse <- sqrt(totVar)) # standard error
}

pooled_rse <- pooled_rse.F(lm_mi)
pooled_rse

#2.980505




#------------------------------------------
```